# Fetch shared storage usage info from windows server

Tags: windows, script, wmic

I am trying to retrieve usage related info of shared storage attached to a server by using:

```
WMIC logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption,drivetype /Format:csv
```

The output is fine. But here the Drive type for drive-D is showing as 3, though its a Netapp Lun. Please let me know how to get Lun information. Its becomes tough for me to identify a Netapp volume if it is showing Netapp as Drivetype 3.
I do not have `powershell` installed in all the servers. So i can not use PS.

OUTPUT:

```
Node,Caption,DriveType,FreeSpace,Size
Hostname,C:,3,1522081792,20973137920
Hostname,D:,3,38534803456,751148986368
Hostname,E:,3,2867924992,52395274240
Hostname,F:,3,44005818368,73364254720
Hostname,R:,5,,
```

Comment: https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1368845/html/GUID-76D42541-0020-4AF8-9815-B884C5ABA211.html